# How do I display different results when a row is selected with a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What I have is a table view with around 5 cells. Each has a different title, and what I want is when the user clicks a certain cell, a certain youtube video pops up pertaining to the title they clicked (all the cells have different titles). I am using WKWebView, and as of right now a Youtube video is popping up whenever a row is clicked, but it's the same Youtube Video no matter what row / title is clicked. How can I get a varying video depending on what row is clicked?

This is the code for the ViewController that contains the cells/titles, the next view controller it moves to is just a file that uses WebKit to display a Youtube Vid with a link.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var motivationalVideoOptions = ["Work Hard And Be Patient", "Put Yourself In A Position To Succeed", "Stop Judging Yourself", "Lose The Battle But Win The War", "Top 10 Rules For Success"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        title = "Choose a video"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return motivationalVideoOptions.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoOptions", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = motivationalVideoOptions[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VideoPlay") as? VideoPlayViewController {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

Other View Controller class:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class VideoPlayViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://youtu.be/T_aFqEmL5JI")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    }
}
```

Comment: What video are you playing in `VideoPlayViewController`? Pls show code of that viewcontroller.

Comment: Without the code for `VideoPlayViewController` one can only assume - it appears you are almost there. Yes, `didSelectRowAt(indexPath:)` is the correct place to both tap into what the user selected and push to the player VC. All you really need to do is pass that VC the value from `motivationalVideoOptions[indexPath.row]`. So I'd suggest you search on how to pass a value to that VC.

Comment: I posted the other code for my view controller class. its just a simple thing to get a url going. anything else that may help you guys I can try and answer. The second class is the one that displays the website once a row is clicked.

Comment: You need a relationship between the video URLs and the `motivationalVideoOptions` array, a custom struct, a second array of the same size and order so you can use the row as index or a few other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it only goes to one video is because you set the url to be constant link. Make a variable that’s based on the title or something with the table view cell data into the url. I am on my phone right now so bear with me.

Example:

I touch this cell that has sub header with the link. I make a reference to the web view and set the link to the sub header of the view. The thing would then load variable link. Which gives you the result you want

Answer (score 0):

What I see in your code is you are passing a constanr youtube URL in every case in VideoPlayViewController.

What you have to do is make a var in your VideoPlayViewController and assign the value to the var on the VC instance you are creating in the didSelectRowAt method in ViewController.

For eg:
Instead of having string values in motivationalVideoOptions you could have a struct or a class. Having 2 variables title and Url. Based on the selection you can fetch the item from the array and pass the url variable.

Comment: So, I made a struct at the top of my ViewController class that holds a title: String, url: String, and an init. I understand what you're saying when I need to assign the var and pass it through the didSelectRowAt method, but how would I pass that through the method? I'm a beginner in iOS. so my knowledge is minimal. I'm having trouble syntax wise on how I would do all this. Sorry for the inconvenience haha.